# After Timeout, User Continues to work without Login in Spring Security/Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, session-timeout

I have created sample App with Spring Security and Spring MVC with CAS Server Authentication.
Spring Security /MVC version:3.1
Problem: After timeout, user is not taken to login page given by JASIG CAS server instead user taken to requested page. But in the debug logs, I can see user session is invalidated and but new session created automatically and continues work .. I attached my logs and security-context.xml for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPER_USER_SA','ROLE_END_USER_SA','ROLE_SUPER_USER_IFA','ROLE_END_USER_IFA')" /> 
        <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter" />
        </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
        </security:authentication-manager>
    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">           
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="logoutFilter" />
            </security:filter-chain-map>
        </bean>
    <!-- sends to the CAS Server, CAS Authentication Entry point -->
  <bean id="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/cas/login" />    
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
      </bean>
      <bean id="logoutFilter" class="co.uk.adminre.groupsandschemes.portal.presentation.listener.CasLogoutFilter">  
<constructor-arg >    <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler"/>    </constructor-arg> 
<constructor-arg>     <list>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>    </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>  

  <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
     <property name="service" value="https://localhost:8443/GroupsAndSchemes-Presentation/j_spring_cas_security_check" />         
      </bean>

    <!-- authenticates CAS tickets -->
  <bean id="casAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/casfailed.jsp" />
          </bean>
        </property>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>

  <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
         <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="authenticationUserDetailsService"/>
         <property name="ticketValidator" ref="ticketValidator"/>
         <property name="serviceProperties"  ref="serviceProperties" />
         <property name="key" value="casJbcpCalendar" />
             <!--     <property name="statelessTicketCache" ref="statelessTicketCache"/> -->
      </bean>

      <!--     <bean id="statelessTicketCache" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.EhCacheBasedTicketCache">
        <property name="cache">
            <bean class="net.sf.ehcache.Cache"
                init-method="initialise" destroy-method="dispose">
                <constructor-arg value="casTickets"/>
                <constructor-arg value="50"/>
                <constructor-arg value="true"/>
                <constructor-arg value="false"/>
                <constructor-arg value="3600"/>
                <constructor-arg value="900"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean> -->

    <bean id="ticketValidator" class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator">
        <constructor-arg value="https://localhost:8443/cas" />       
        </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.cas.userdetails.GrantedAuthorityFromAssertionAttributesUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg>
          <array>
                <value>FullName        </value>
                            <value>LastName        </value>
                            <value>role        </value>
                            <value>telephoneNumber        </value>
                </array>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

debug logs:

```
                            |          |2013-09-26 18:50:04,660|org.hdiv.listener.InitListener|INFO|HDIV's session destroyed:6427E5C51797126090DBBFFF661151A9
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository|DEBUG|No HttpSession currently exists
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository|DEBUG|No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CasAuthenticationFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|serviceTicketRequest = false
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|proxyReceptorConfigured = false
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|proxyReceptorRequest = false
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|proxyTicketRequest = false
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|requiresAuthentication = false
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '    org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details:     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter|DEBUG|Requested session ID 6427E5C51797126090DBBFFF661151A9 is invalid.
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80 at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor|DEBUG|Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80; Attributes: [hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPER_USER_SA','ROLE_END_USER_SA','ROLE_SUPER_USER_IFA','ROLE_END_USER_IFA')]
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,789|    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor|DEBUG|Previously Authenticated:     org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details:     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,790|    org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased|DEBUG|Voter:     org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@91af0f, returned: -1
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,790|    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter|DEBUG|Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at     org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
at     org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
at     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.selva.base.portal.infrastructure.MDCFilter.doFilterInternal(MDCFilter.java:47)
at     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,822|    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|DEBUG|Creating instance of bean 'cache'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,822|    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|DEBUG|Invoking init method  'init' on bean with name 'cache'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,822|    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|DEBUG|Finished creating instance of bean 'cache'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,822|    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|DEBUG|Creating instance of bean 'pageIdGenerator'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,822|    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|DEBUG|Finished creating instance of bean 'pageIdGenerator'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,822|    org.hdiv.listener.InitListener|INFO|HDIV's session created:1C07D8BC2E69EC543F785B8209FF8350
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,823|    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache|DEBUG|DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[https://localhost:8443/base-Presentation/portal/home?execution=e1s1&_eventId=getSchemeSummary&action=0&schemeId=0&collectionNumber=0&1177981884=19-6-612269E5540BA3BB13968B9F719D8A80]
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,823|    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter|DEBUG|Calling Authentication entry point.
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,823|    org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository|DEBUG|SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,823|    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter|DEBUG|SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-2-gWAwHig4UcUSYL5sUSvk-cas at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository|DEBUG|HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository|DEBUG|No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession:     org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1eb5a32. A new one will be created.
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-2-gWAwHig4UcUSYL5sUSvk-cas at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy|DEBUG|/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-2-gWAwHig4UcUSYL5sUSvk-cas at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CasAuthenticationFilter'
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|serviceTicketRequest = true
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|requiresAuthentication = true
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|Request is to process authentication
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|proxyReceptorConfigured = false
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|proxyReceptorRequest = false
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|serviceTicketRequest = true
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager|DEBUG|Authentication attempt using     org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider|DEBUG|serviceUrl = https://localhost:8443/base-Presentation/j_spring_cas_security_check
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator|DEBUG|Placing URL parameters in map.
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator|DEBUG|Calling template URL attribute map.
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator|DEBUG|Loading custom parameters from configuration.
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator|DEBUG|Constructing validation url: https://localhost:8443/cas/samlValidate?TARGET=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Fbase-Presentation%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,866|    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator|DEBUG|Retrieving response from server.
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,877|    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator|DEBUG|Server response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.    org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.    org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.    org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" IssueInstant="2013-09-26T13:25:22.873Z" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" Recipient="https://localhost:8443/base-Presentation/j_spring_cas_security_check" ResponseID="_1a7d854b2579e8d0793bf121230ee650"><Status><StatusCode Value="samlp:Success"></StatusCode></Status><Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" AssertionID="_a43b14e66a324ea7cf366eab6437745a" IssueInstant="2013-09-26T13:25:22.873Z" Issuer="localhost" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1"><Conditions NotBefore="2013-09-26T13:25:22.873Z" NotOnOrAfter="2013-09-26T13:25:52.873Z"><AudienceRestrictionCondition><Audience>https://localhost:8443/base-Presentation/j_spring_cas_security_check</Audience></AudienceRestrictionCondition></Conditions><AttributeStatement><Subject><NameIdentifier>eu_sa_active@selva.com</NameIdentifier><SubjectConfirmation><ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:artifact</ConfirmationMethod></SubjectConfirmation></Subject><Attribute AttributeName="FullName" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.    org/products/cas/"><AttributeValue>EUSA</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute AttributeName="role" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.    org/products/cas/"><AttributeValue>ROLE_END_USER_SA</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>Active</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute AttributeName="LastName" AttributeNamespace="http://www.ja-sig.    org/products/cas/"><AttributeValue>EU</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement><AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2013-09-26T13:18:16.422Z" AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:unspecified"><Subject><NameIdentifier>eu_sa_active@selva.com</NameIdentifier><SubjectConfirmation><ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:artifact</ConfirmationMethod></SubjectConfirmation></Subject></AuthenticationStatement></Assertion></Response></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,879|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|serviceTicketRequest = true
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1     |null      |2013-09-26 18:55:22,879|    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter|DEBUG|Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain:     org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationToken@744ab48a: Principal:     org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@1f89a334: Username: eu_sa_active@selva.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ACTIVE,EU,EUSA,ROLE_END_USER_SA; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details:
```

Updated:
I have written a custom logoutfilter to handle both logout and sessiontimeout.

```
   public class CasLogoutFilter extends LogoutFilter  implements
ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

 public CasLogoutFilter(LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler,
        LogoutHandler... handlers) {

    super(logoutSuccessHandler, handlers);
 } @Override
public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
    this.event=event;
    System.out.println(" Session over Calling CASLogout");
    new CasLogoutFilter(logoutSuccessHandler, localHandler);
}

}
```

I registered HttpSessionEventPublisher in web.xml . After timout the ondestroy method is called and illegal argument exception is throwing in LogoutFilter.

Thanks,
Selva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is anything wrong. You are being redirected to the CAS server but since you still have a valid CAS session, it isn't asking you to log in and redirects you back to Spring Security with a new session ticket. So the process is transparent.

If you monitor the network requests from your browser using firebug or chrome's developer tools (or use tcpdump) it should be obvious that's what's happening.

Comment: Thank you. After the security context,security context holder and Http Session are cleared , Is there any way for me to get the CAS session get Cleared(From Spring Security Perspective)?

Comment: The CAS logout request has to come from the user's browser (since that is where the CAS session cookie is), so if the user logs out of your app, you can redirect them there (or show a page, suggesting they might want to also log out of CAS). If their session just times out in your app, then you can't log them out of CAS at the same time.

Comment: I have a filter by extending Logout Filter and implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> , to handle both the sessiontimout and logout. Also , in sec-ctxt.xml i added like below..<bean id="logoutFilter" class="co.uk.adminre.groupsandschemes.portal.presentation.listener.CasLogoutFilter">  
  <constructor-arg ><bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler"/></constructor-arg> 
  <constructor-arg><list><bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/></list></constructor-arg></bean>

Comment: Please edit your question (or ask a new one if this is a different issue) rather than using comments.